# getting data from arraylist<object> and parse it

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I craet arraylist<object[]> for storing values
2.

```
   ArrayList<Object[]> custInfo = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); 
   while(rs.next()){
                String loginId = rs.getString("LOGIN_ID");
                String  customerId = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID") ;
                String  requestDate = rs.getString("REQUEST_DATE") ;
                String updateUser  = rs.getString("UPDATE_USER") ;
                
                 Object[] custInfo123 = {loginId, customerId, requestDate, updateUser };
                 custInfo.add(custInfo123);
            }  
   session.setAttribute("custInfo", custInfo);
```

and now, Im using arraylist in another jsp

```
  ArrayList<String> custInfo = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("custInfo");
```

Now I want to get data from this arraylist but i dont know how to do that.

I want value like
customer1-loginid, customerid, requestdate, updateuser
customer2- loginid, customerid, requestdate, updateuser
customer3- loginid, customerid, requestdate, updateuser

how can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on each object to find the one with the right attribute but a better approach is to use a rowmapper with typed objects e.g. CustomerInformation
like this example : https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

and if you want to access it with a specific property I would rather use a HashMap with this property as key so you'll have to iterate only on objects whitches have that field value or directly return a list for this key.

An even better solution is to query from database only rows matching theises properties.

```
    public List<CustomerInformation> findCustomersById(String customerId) {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE LOGIN_ID = '" + customerId + "'";

    ArrayList<Object[]> custInfo = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    while(rs.next()){
        String loginId = rs.getString("LOGIN_ID");
        String  customerId = rs.getString("CUSTOMER_ID") ;
        String  requestDate = rs.getString("REQUEST_DATE") ;
        String updateUser  = rs.getString("UPDATE_USER") ;

        Object[] custInfo123 = {loginId, customerId, requestDate, updateUser };
        custInfo.add(custInfo123);
    }
    return custInfo;
}
```